# iMac 10,1 allegedly does not support nvram, and takes longer than usual to boot. What could be the issue?

Tags: imac, startup, nvram

[image]

Command+Option+P+R does nothing, and executing `nvram -xp` and `nvram -c` returns the same `nvram is not supported on this system`

This is on a clean install of Yosemite (installation of El Cap and above fails every time), on a SATA internal SSD.

Edit: The underlying issue I'm trying to fix is slow boot times. Yosemite is installed on an SSD, yet it still takes about 2 minutes and 20 seconds to boot up. I've recorded a video of it booting up in verbose mode, but I've yet to decide whether to upload that or try to get a text dump of the console.

Edit 2: Watch the iMac boot in real-time, with verbose output: https://streamable.com/9fa6h6

Edit 3: Output of `ioreg -p IODeviceTree` https://pastebin.com/BGJvkYea

Edit 4: Boot ROM is `IM101.00CC.B00` and SMC version (system) is `1.53f13`. There is nothing in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Firmware Updates/`.

Any chance that something like this (https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/adxdb0/the_bodgers_guide_to_getting_nvram_working/) can fix it, partially or otherwise?

Comment: Is a firmware password set? Are you using a wired keyboard for the c/o/p/r at boot?

Comment: No FW password is set. I’ve tried both wired and wireless keyboard for the key combo on boot.

Comment: Let’s see if the NVRAM KEXT is properly loading. Please provide the output of: $ kextstat | grep EFI and $ ioreg -r -c AppleEFINVRAM

Comment: Here’s the output: https://pastebin.com/c9148zKW

Comment: NVRAM is present and has valid data, ruling out a broken KEXT or a corrupt NVRAM flash region. The slow boot is definitely not normal and likely to be related to your NVRAM issue. It appears to be stalling while enumerating the PCI bus. Do you have any devices attached to you Mac?

Comment: Do you have a lt of Apps that start on login (or boot). This could slow it down a lot.

Comment: @jmh If you observe the verbose boot video, you will see that the stalls occur prior to any launch agents or login items spawning. They occur in the device configuration phase.

Comment: Ok, i couldn't make out what was happening in the video.

Comment: @pion No devices are connected to the Mac other than an Apple wireless keyboard and Magic Mouse via Bluetooth.

Comment: @Natsfan It’s a clean installation of Mac OS, so only the apps that it normally loads start on boot.

Comment: Please append the output of `ioreg -p IODeviceTree` to your question.

Comment: @pion Appended.

Comment: `options` is missing from your `IODeviceTree` which is why I suspect this is all happening. Can you tell us your system firmware version? (`Apple Menu -> About This Mac -> System Report -> Hardware`)

Comment: Boot ROM version is ```IM101.00CC.B00``` and SMC version (system) is ```1.53f13```.

Comment: @aklh Do you see anything in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Firmware Updates/`?

Comment: Nope there is nothing in there.

Comment: Can you try boot your Mac on external disk with High Sierra (the last system supported by this Mac) installed on this external disk?

Comment: The progress bar takes about 15 minutes to reach the end, then never finishes booting.